# Ansible HTTPS connection wrong SSL version

Tags: python, https, ansible, winrm

I tried to connect to my windows 7 machine using Ansible using credssp I'm recieving the error as below.

`tls_server_hello,wrong_ssl_version`.

Whereas when I tried the same in my windows 10 machine I'm able to do **win_ping**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is directly from [Ansible docs.](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_windows.html#credssp-and-tls-1-2) The problem is that Windows 7 defaults to using TLS 1.0, but ansible needs TLS 1.2.

You can test which version WinRM uses with openssl, for example:

```
openssl s_client -connect your_win7_remote_host:5986

Protocol displayed has to be TLSv1.2. Follow the steps in link provided to create necessary registry keys and after restart it should work. That is:

Create entry DefaultSecureProtocols with value 0x00000800 (for TLSv1.2 only) or 0x00000A00 (for both TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2) in keys 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp

and (for x64 machines)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WinHttp

Create entry DisabledByDefault with value 0 in key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue and ended up here.

Googling lead me to believe that this might be because third party root certificates on the windows host might have somehow been borked. Was it a bad update? Was it a dangerous user? Who knows! Who cares!

I did the following, and it resolved my connection issues:

1) Delete **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\AuthRoot\Certificates**

2) Reboot

No more SSL wrong version error

Comment: But these kind of errors I got only for Windows 7 machines. Whereas in Windows 8 and Windows 10 works like Bread and Butter!

Comment: Windows was a mistake.

Comment: But, **WinRM** is a lot more like **SSH** through **HTTP**, which is a lot better with **Chef** rather than **Ansible**

Comment: Yeah I've seen complaints about WinRM being iffy via ansible in a few places when diagnosing timeout errors. Seeing as how I would rather kill myself than use Chef, oh well!